# MSSQL trigger value

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Lets say my table has 2 value.after insert statement,how to i get the insert record data and insert it to the trigger?I am using entity framework for CRUD events.

```
//orginalTable has 2 fields for example.

    CREATE TRIGGER originalTable_Audit ON [originalTable] 
 AFTER  INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    -- Insert statements for trigger here
INSERT INTO originalTable_Audit  values(@value,@value2,@action,@updatedBy)
```

do i have to pull it myself?if yes,how to ensure that the record i am pulling is always correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sql Server triggers uses two pseudo tables calls `inserted` and `deleted` that keeps the records effected by the statement that fired the trigger.
In a trigger for insert, the `deleted` table will be empty, of course, but the `inserted` table will have all the records that was inserted to the table (or supposed to be inserted, in case of an `instead of` trigger.)

**Important Note**: In Sql Server, triggers fire per statement, not per row. This means that even if your insert statement inserted 3 records, the trigger will only be fired once, and your `inserted` table will contain all 3 records.
When writing triggers, you must be aware of this fact, otherwise you might get exceptions, or even worst, wrong data (worst since you wouldn't know it in real time)

For further reading, Please refer to [the relevant page in Microsoft's documentatin.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx)

So your trigger should look like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER originalTable_Audit ON [originalTable] 
AFTER  INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    -- Insert statements for trigger here
    INSERT INTO originalTable_Audit (<Columns List of originalTable_Audit>)
    SELECT <Columns List of originalTable>
    FROM insterted
END
```

Comment: Thanks. it works. i googled else where and i thought the inserted is a self declared table. after trying out then realized it is from mssql